# Phone is too flat to charge

Tags: cyanogenmod, battery, charging

My phone died today, and now it won't charge at all on the charger it came with. I don't think the battery has failed, as it still gives me just as much charge on a full charge as always. The phone is an LG P500 running CM7.

My battery charged perfectly in another model of the same phone. Does this suggest there is an actual problem with my phone?

What can I do to get my phone to start charging?

Comment: What do you mean by `phone died`?

Comment: Battery went flat.

Comment: But, you don't believe your battery has failed. Is your phone working?

Comment: Have you tried charging with another charger?

Comment: The phone was working perfectly fine. It had been on for about 3 days without needing a charge but as I away from home last night I didn't get a chance to charge it before it went flat this morning. I did try my brothers charger as he has the same phone, but it's not working.

Comment: Its possible that your charging interface went flat. To test it, insert your battery in your bros phone and try charging.

Comment: It seems like you are correct. Upon putting my battery in his phone and plugging the charger in, it immediately started charging correctly, giving me a charge indicator.

Answer (score 3):

The phone should *always* charge, no matter how empty the battery is. You imply that the empty battery is the reason why it wouldn't charge, but I think that this is not true.

It is more likely that you are dealing with a hardware issue here. But first make sure that you connect the charger for at least an hour to your phone, just to make sure that it is really not charging. Even if there is no visual feedback of the charge process, there is still a chance that it does so. You could also try swapping the battery with the one from your brother, to see if the failure is the battery or with the phone.

Comment: To start with, my brothers battery worked perfectly. I've had the phone on charge for approximately 30 minutes and all it seems to do is *try* and boot, briefly showing the LG logo before it flicks off, repeating itself a few minutes later.

Comment: Answer seems to be what Sachin suggested in the above comments. Battery is now charging in my brothers phone.

Answer (score 1):

The same happened to me, try plugging it in to a laptop with a usb cable. for some reason that was the only way the phone would charge while it was turned off or compleatly flat.